# C++ Passing C-style string as argument

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm having some trouble dealing with C-style strings in c++. In short what I'm trying to do is pass a cstring from my main method into the constructors of one of my objects.

For example

```
class sample
{
  public: // Initalization
  Sample( const char * inFile);
}//End sample class
```

Then in the main method.

```
//Main method
int main ( int argc, const char * argv[] )
{
   Sample aSample(argv[1]);
}
```

Now, based on my assumption I should be getting back a `const char*` when I dereference the second pointer using `argv[1]`. From my understanding `char *argv[]` is just another way of saying char `**argv`.

Also, just to make sure my understanding of const is correct, `const char *` is saying "this pointer points to a const char" where `const char const *` is saying " this pointer address can not be changed, and the address it points to is const as well".

Update -

Just to clarify this is a two part question.

1. If the constructor in sample is incorrect for passing a cstring, how can I correct it?
2. Understanding of const

Updated my incorrect statement above that i dereferenced the "first" pointer when it should have been the "second". Thank you below for pointing that out.

2nd update -
I'm using argv[1] because I'm receiving information from the command line and argv[0] holds only the path of the executable, which I'm not interested in.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

-Freddy

Comment: yes, I'm getting an error that the symbol is undefined for the constructor I'm trying to call.

"Simple::Simple(char const*), referenced from:
_Main in unit.o

Thats why I was asking about my understanding of const was correct. I thought the interface of my argument may have been incorrect.

Comment: Ah -- well, that just means you haven't defined what the sample constructor is supposed to do.  You've declared it, but not defined it.

Comment: I'm starting to think It might be an issue with the IDE that I'm using. I have tried to clean and rebuild, but I have fully defined the constructor in my .cpp file.

Comment: Do you have more than one .cpp file?

Comment: Looks like a linker error, not a compiler error.

Comment: Turns out it was an issue with target not getting the updated .cpp file. Once I deleted all compiled dependencies and re-added built and ran just fine. errr -1 for xcode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`argv[1]` dereferences the second pointer, not the first. You want `argv[0]`. Arrays in C++ are *0-based*.

Also:

```
const char const *
```

isn't legal (credits to Benjamin for pointing it out). Both `const`s are applied to the `char` in this case. If you want the pointer to be const, you need

```
char const * const
```

or

```
const char * const
```

EDIT:

Question 1) A CString can take a `char*` as parameter for the constructor, so it should work.

Question 2) `const` binds to the left, unless there's nothing to the left. So `const char` and `char const` are the same. For a const pointer, you need `* const`, not `const *`.

Comment: *"argv[1] dereferences the first pointer, not the second"* -- Don't you have that backwards?  Also, `const char const *
` is redundant.

Comment: Thanks Luchian on correcting me on the const pointer information. However, in c++ isn't argv[0] the path to the executable? In my main if i print argv[1] it is printing the correct information that was passed in the command line.

Comment: @Freddy well, you said "when I dereference the first pointer using argv[1]", which is a mistake.

Comment: In addition to being redundant, it's also an error, but your answer says it's a valid declaration (that's why I pointed it out)